# Robots.txt (allow)

Tags: shopify, robots.txt

I have a Shopify store.
My robots.txt disallow everything. How do I “allow” it back.
Here’s the photo[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxsIb.png)

Comment: Don't use images of code, post the code itself here, with the proper formatting.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there after fixing the screenshot issue (pasting in your robots.txt flie directtly.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.